# How do I find values of $a,b,c,$ and $d$ of a $2\times 2$ matrix given these eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

> You are told that a matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 8$. Calculate the value of $a^2+7ad-5bc+d^2$.

What I have done so far is multiplied the identity ($2\times 2$) matrix by each eigenvalue and formed two equations by subtracting them from $a,b,c,d$ matrix and then performing $ad-bc = 0$ for each one, so that there are two equations that can be solved simultaneously. I hope that made some sense and I am not good at describing maths. Am I correct? 
Thank you!

Comment: so far ive got a=9-d Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$a^2+7ad-5bc+d^2=(a+d)^2+5(ad-bc)$$

Think of how determinant and trace relates to eigenvalues.

Remark:

To verify your answer, just work with $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 8\end{bmatrix}$. Also, $a,b,c,d$ is not uniquely determined. For example, $\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 0  \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ satisfy the condition too. You have to prove that the value of $a^2+7ad-5bc+d^2$ is unique even though there is some flexibility in choosing the value of $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: I have no idea how, i would really appreciate an explanation

Comment: @RandyRogers determinant is a product of eigenvalues, trace is their sum

Comment: Im a bit confused with what i have to do. Dont i need to find the values of a,b,c, and d first?

Comment: No. You don't have to. In fact, you can't uniquely determine $a,b,c,d$ as I have illustrated that it is not unique. Focus on finding the value of $a+d$ and $ad-bc$. gt6989b is giving you a very big hint. use the hint.

Comment: trace is  a + d =9 which is equal to sum of eigenvalues, and ad - bc = 8, product of eigenvalues. So can a= 8 and d =1 and c=0 and b=0 and then just sub these values into a^2+7ad−5bc +d^2 to get 121? Im new to this so forgive me for being so slow

Comment: You have obtained $\color{blue}{a+d}$ and $\color{green}{ad-bc}$,  hence we can compute $(\color{blue}{a+d})^2+5(\color{green}{ad-bc})$.  While $a,b,c,d$ can take those value, they need not take those value. $121$ is the correct answer. btw, take your time, it's ok to be slow. It takes time to learn. Take your time to let concept sink in, don't rush.