# How to find matrix given only 2 eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets say the matrix is a 2x2 matrix, with unknown values a,b,c,d and your given that eigenvalues are λ =7 and λ =10 and your asked to calculate the value of a^2+3ad−bc+d^2.

Comment: Place them on the diagonal. That's one option.

Comment: There are many matrices with that property.

Comment: This is basically the same as [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2554248/265466), and the same approach given in the answer to that one applies here as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no unique such matrix. It could be
$$
\pmatrix{7 & 0 \\ 0 & 10},
$$
or
$$
\pmatrix{17 & -3 \\ -3 & 17},
$$
or any matrix similar to this one.

For the modified question, where you are looking for $a^2+3ad−bc+d^2,$ note that the determinant and the trace (the sum of all diagonal elements) are functions of the eigenvalues.

Specifically, $\det M = ad-bc$ equals the product of the eigenvalues, i.e., 70, while $\operatorname{trace} M=a+d$ equals the sum of the eigenvalues, i.e., 17. So we have
$$
a^2+3ad−bc+d^2 = (a+d)^2 + ad-bc = (\operatorname{trace} M)^2 + \det M = 17^2+70 = 359.
$$

Comment: what if the questiosn then asks to calculate the value of a^2+3 a d−b c+d^2 ?

Comment: That is a very different question. This quantity might be the same for all these matrices.

Comment: how would you solve this question?

Comment: Actually, the answer can still not be determined, since you can double all entries of a matrix without changing eigenvalues, but changing values of the expression. In general, I would approach such a question by looking at determinants and traces, which are functions of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I take my last comment back.

Comment: from what i remember am i correct to say the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace and the product of the eigenvalues is equal to the determinant ad-bc ?

Comment: Yes, I am just enhancing my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome!